# Firefox: What's the shortcut for "Match Case" and how to change it?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I know "Highlight All" is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, but I can't figure out what the shortcut for "Match Case" when using the Find function. I'd also like to know how to change it, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

#### I can't figure out what the shortcut for "Match Case" when using the Find function.

Use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to toggle "Match Case". This is shown by the underline on the `c` of "Match Case":

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for Mac OSX...

Comment: You didn't specify OSX in your question :/ Your question mentioned  ctrl+a which implies Windows. I gave you an answer for Windows. (OSX "select all" is cmd+a)